# javaBean Can't detect the class property

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

Testing environment: netbeans7.11 + glassfish 3.11
here is the jsp, class code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean id="gb" class="GameBean" scope="session" />
<jsp:setProperty name="gb" property="operation" value="OOOOOOOOO" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><jsp:getProperty name="gb" property="operation" /></h1>
    </body>
</html>



public class GameBean {
    private String operation; //operation

    public void setOperation (String operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    public String getOperation () {
       return this.operation;
    }

}


Error message: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6054: Cannot find any information  on property 'operation' in a bean of type 'GameBean'
C:\Users\ray\Desktop\OU\COMPS311\tma02\web\nbproject\build-impl.xml:612: Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

why can't detect the operation?

After set the method to public

```
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\test\web\build\generated\classes
C:\Users\test\web\build\generated\src\org\apache\jsp\GameBean_jsp.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
      GameBean GameBean = null;
      ^
  symbol:   class GameBean
  location: class GameBean_jsp
C:\Users\test\web\build\generated\src\org\apache\jsp\GameBean_jsp.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
        GameBean = (GameBean) _jspx_page_context.getAttribute("GameBean", PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE);
  symbol:   class GameBean
  location: class GameBean_jsp
C:\Users\test\web\build\generated\src\org\apache\jsp\GameBean_jsp.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
          GameBean = new GameBean();
  symbol:   class GameBean
  location: class GameBean_jsp
C:\Users\test\web\build\generated\src\org\apache\jsp\GameBean_jsp.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
      out.write(org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.toString((((GameBean)_jspx_page_context.findAttribute("GameBean")).getOperation())));
  symbol:   class GameBean
  location: class GameBean_jsp
4 errors
C:\Users\test\web\nbproject\build-impl.xml:629: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\test\web\nbproject\build-impl.xml:263: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `getOperation()` and `setOperation(...)` methods **public**.

After your updates the new issue seems to be that your `GameBean` is defined in some package which you are not importing (or using the fully qualified name) in JSP.

Comment: but there is no package has been defined

Comment: @hkinterview Here http://www.javafixer.org/cannot-find-symbol.php is the explanation for the error you are getting. I suggest you read it and see where the issue is.